# Name for the top left cell of a table

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name for the top left cell of a table? The one next to the column headers and above the row headers. Does it even have a technical name?

E.g. the cell with `???` in this table:

```
+-----+------+------+
|???  |Yes   |No    |
+-------------------+
|A    |1     |4     |
|B    |2     |5     |
|C    |3     |6     |
+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: "Top left" is normal, but if you said "first cell" people would get what you meant too.

Comment: I guess there could be a nickname among typographers, as that cell is quite special, but I wouldn't know what it is.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a perfectly good question: not easy to google for it, this term might exist or might not, so asking it here is entirely appropriate.

Comment: "Top left" is clear (at least for RTL languages). "First cell" is good but could refer to the first data cell (`1` in my example).

Comment: @dave1010 Yep that's a fair point about "first cell".

Comment: Why would “top left” make more sense in a right-to-left language than in a left-to-right one?

Comment: @tchrist He probably meant LTR, and also that tables can extend arbitrarily far in the text direction, so the LTR top-right cell is not special and may be infinitely far away.

Comment: Calling it the *foremost* cell probably would be well understood

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The top left corner of any display is called the [***Canton***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canton_%28heraldry%29) in English heraldry.
In the U.S. flag, for instance, the blue part with white stars is the canton.

In a table, it's usually blank because the top row and left column are labels, not data;
so whatever appears in the top left box can't be either. Thus it's available for special purposes.

Comment: Very nice.  I often use a bend sinister in that cell — so ⧅ with text in both halves. That way I can separately and unambiguously label the column headers extending to the right of that cell and the row headers beneath it.

Comment: I do much the same thing, though I rarely hafta deal with spreadsheets these days.

Comment: Can you use _canton_ for a table and table cell?

Comment: You certainly can if you want to. Spreadsheets are entirely new technology and, like all such, use entirely metaphorical terminology; there certainly is no specific term for it hallowed by centuries of tradition. The only problem is whether anybody will understand _canton_ in the appropriate heraldic way; my guess is that few will -- because heraldry is a fairly rare topic of interest -- so you'll hafta sell the term yourself if you use it. But there's certainly no reason why you can't.

Comment: I have no idea. As I said, this is all new territory; you pays your money and you takes your choice.

Answer (score 3):

It’s called the *northwest corner cell*.

For example:

> Select the northwest corner cell of the transportation table and allocate as many  units as possible equal to the minimum between availability supply and demand. . . .

Comment: I'm not convinced that this would identify the right cell when there are header rows and/or columns as in the OP. Your example, for example, is talking about data, so if the table had headers I would assume it meant the top-left *data* cell. The more I think about it the less convinced I am that there is an answer that unambiguously identifies the correct cell, in the case with headers.

Comment: ...unless, of course, the answer explicitly mentions headers as @ermanen's does.

Comment: @Rube `cell[0][0] = "⧅"`

Answer (score 2):

It is called ***first header cell***, especially in programming.

It is also  mentioned in the [table style element order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.tablestyleelement%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on MSDN site.

Comment: Frequently the cell referred to in the question is empty, so some people may actually refer to the cell next to it as the "first header cell".

Comment: @pacoverflow: Even when it is empty, it is still called first header cell.